# Set log format on logger (without basicConfig)

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I'm declaring and setting the log level on a `logger` object like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
loglevel = 'DEBUG' # actually taken from a config in my code
logger.setLevel(logging.getLevelName(loglevel))
```

**How can I set the log format in this case?** I tried `logger.setFormat` and `logger.setFormatter`, they throw attribute errors.

Every guide I read talks about `logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)`, but I'm using a `logger` and not calling directly `logging`.

Answer (score 4):

There is an example in the docs, [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging). 
Create a handler, set the formatter, then add the handler to the logger:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(console)
logger.debug('Hi')
```

prints

```
__main__    : Hi
```